# Extending the Jenkins Groovy DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How can I add/edit new code to my Jenkins instance that would be accesible in a DSL script?  Context follows

I've inherited a Jenkins instance.  Part of this inheritance includes <strike>spending the night in a haunted house</strike> writing some new automation [in groovy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) via the [Jobs DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin).  Since I'm fearful of ruining our jenkins instance, my first step is setting up a local development instance.

I'm having trouble running one of our existing *DSL Scripts* on my local development instance -- my builds on the local server fail with the following in the Jenkins error console.

```
Processing DSL script jobs.groovy
ERROR: startup failed:
jobs.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class thecompanysname.jenkins.extensions
```

The script in question starts off like this.

```
import thecompanysname.jenkins.extensions

use(extensions) {
  def org = 'project-name'
  def project = 'test-jenkins-repo'
  def _email = 'foo@example.com'
```

So, as near I can tell, it seems like a predecesor has written some custom Groovy code that they're importing

```
import thecompanysname.jenkins.extensions
```

What's not clear to me is

1. Where this code lives
2. How I can find it in our real Jenkins instance
3. How I can add to to my local instance

Specific answers are welcome, as our *here's how you can learn to fish* answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there may be other ways to accomplish this, after a bit of poking around I discovered

1. The Jenkins instance I've installed has an older version of the [Jobs DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) installed.
2. This version of the Jobs DSL plugin allowed you to set an additional `classpath` in your *Process DSL Builds* job section that pointed to additional `jar` files.
3. These jar files can give you access to additional classes in your groovy scripts (i.e. `thecompanysname.jenkins.extensions`)

Unfortunately, more recent versions of the *Jobs DSL plugin* have removed this option, and it's not clear if it's possible to add it back.  That, however, is another question.

Comment: Not sure if it will be helpful, but I think the additional classpath option is related to the global script security option.  Going from memory, with that disabled globally, you have the additional classpath option for a job dsl build step.

Answer (score 1):

Configure Global Security -> uncheck "Enable script security for Job DSL
scripts".
works for me