# Loading Custom jar files in Jenkins without the Classpath Field

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jar, classpath

How can I load a custom jar file for my *Jenkins Jobs DSL* groovy scripts *without* the classpath field?

I've inherited a Jenkins instance.  This Jenkins instance has an older version of the [Jenkins Jobs DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin).  This version of the jobs plugin has a class path fields

[image]

By loading this jar file, my script (in the DSL Scripts) has additional symbols/classes [it may import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718207/extending-the-jenkins-groovy-dsl/47723776#47723776).

However, the latest versions of the *Jenkins Jobs DSL* have removed this class path field.  The impression I get from [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/job-dsl-plugin)) is this was done for security reasons.

Without this option, is it possible to set a different class path (or include extra `jar` files in my *Jenkins Jobs DSL* groovy scripts without this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any direct option available. Following are the options available

**Option 1**: As Daniel has suggested (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/job-dsl-plugin/lYgX3boW0Pk) , you can use the Script Security Plugin to add custom classpath and include the jar(s). The only overhead with this approach is, even if there is a minor difference in the jar, an approval would be required.

**Option 2**(Least Preferred, Last Option): If you are running Jenkins under a company network and if your confident on security, then you can consider to uncheck the Enable Security for Job DSL from Jenkins-> Configure Global Secutiry [image]